# how to get a row from sql table which have a column value equal to maximum of count of a column value of same sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a roles table
which contains three fields

```
actor_id, movie_id, role
```

where actor_id and movie_id are integer and role is the string.

We can get movie_id and their corresponding how many actors acted in that movie using

```
select r.movie_id, count(r.actor_id)
from roles r
group by r.movie_id;
```

I wan to get that movie_id and their corresponding count(r.actor_id) which have count(r.actor_id) value equal to the maximum of all the count(r.actor_id).
I used max with count(r.actor_id) using:

```
select r.movie_id, count(r.actor_id)
from roles r
where count(r.actor_id) = max(count(r.actor_id))
group by r.movie_id;
```

But this above gives error
How should we do it.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Which version ?

Comment: @Asis  . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Comment: Figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)
and update accordingly.

Comment: I am using MySQL 8.0.19.0

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only one movie id, then use `order by` and some way of limiting the results:

```
select r.movie_id, count(*)
from roles r
group by r.movie_id
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

The last clause is database dependent.  It might be `select top (1)` or `limit 1`.

If you want duplicates, then use `rank()`:

```
select movie_id, cnt
from (select r.movie_id, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from roles r
      group by r.movie_id
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: But there can be multiple movie_id for which count(actor_id) value equal to the maximum of this.

Comment: Can you please tell me how this rank() and over works?

Comment: @Asis . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank.